# bootstrap grid to fill page width and height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following 4 squares (two rows and two columns):

```
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">                    
                 <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">                    
                <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">                    
                <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">                    
                <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I would like them to be displayed in a 4 square fashion and that the grid takes the whole width and height of the page. I also want it to be responsive and I don't want any spaces between each square.

I tried setting the css on my section tag like this:

```
section
{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

But that had no effect. Does anybody know how to achieve this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the CSS

```
section#gallery
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

div.row
{
    height:50%;
}

div.col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
{
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/01djtnyd/

**note: I changed all classes to "-6" so you can see it work easily in the fiddle**

add class `no-padding` to the divs that are wrapping the img div

in the css add this:

```
.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.no-padding > div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `css flexbox` and jQuery. Here are two options to maintain the `square` shape of each div.

Option 1:

HTML:

```
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row grid-wrapper">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-block">                    
                 <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-block">                    
                <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row grid-wrapper">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-block">                    
                <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-block">                    
                <div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/675x400)">&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section
{
  height: 100vh;
}
.grid-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.grid-block{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var grid_w = $(".grid-block").width();
  $(".grid-block").height(grid_w);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puxLmy1y/2/

Option 2 (without jQuery):

HTML: Same as above

CSS:

```
section
{
  height: 100vh;
}
.grid-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.grid-block{
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/puxLmy1y/3/